# node js custom localized string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am just learning node js. I want to localize a string. This is where I'm at right now.

```js
var globals = {
  enUS: {
      color:'color is {0}',
      cell:'cell phone'
  },
  enGB: {
      color: 'colour is {0}',
      cell: 'mobile phone'
  }
};
```

what i want to do is assign blue to globals["enUS"].color. so I want to output "color is blue" in the console. or when I assign red, I want to output "color is red". how do I fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var globals = {
  colorG: 'blue', //default
  enUS: {
    color: (color = globals.colorG) => `color is ${color}`,
    cell: "cell phone"
  },
  enGB: {
    color: (color = globals.colorG) => `color is ${color}`,
    cell: "mobile phone"
  }
};

console.log(globals["enUS"].color());
console.log(globals["enGB"].color('purple'));
```

You can change the default color or pass any color of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates to insert variables inside strings.

```js
var color = "red"; // or whatever you want

var globals = {
  enUS: {
    color: `color is ${color}`,
    cell: "cell phone"
  },
  enGB: {
    color: `colour is ${color}`,
    cell: "mobile phone"
  }
};

console.log(globals["enUS"].color);
console.log(globals["enGB"].color);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var VAR_COLOR='red';
var globals = {
  enUS: {
      color:`color is ${VAR_COLOR}`,
      cell:'cell phone'
  },
  enGB: {
      color: `colour is ${VAR_COLOR}`,
      cell: 'mobile phone'
  }
};
```

You can try using the VAR_COLOR like this